# PHP Table cannot be styled

Tags: php, html, css

I got a homework that tells me to connect MySQL database to our PHP files and echo it in an HTML table. I managed to connect it, but my problem is I cannot style the table, the other element seems fine, so I think the stylesheet is linked properly.

This is my PHP ->

```
<div id="stats" class="stats">
    <center><h2>Statistic.</h2></center>
    

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Degree</th>
            <th>Institution</th>
            <th>Graduate</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_edu");
        if ($conn -> connect_error) {
            die("Connection Failed:". $conn -> connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM edu";
        $result = $conn -> query($sql);

        if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>". $row["number"] ."</td><td>". $row["degree"] ."</td><td>". $row["name"] ."</td><td>". $row["graduate"] ."</td></tr>";
            }  
        }
        else {
            echo "0 result";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>

    </table>
    

</div>
```

The table is printed, as you can see here

[image: table]

and this is the one that was supposed to style the table

```
.stats table{
width: 800px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;   
padding: 3px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```css
/*STATISTIC*/
.stats{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.stats h2{
    padding: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.stats h3{
    padding-top: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.stats table{
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;   
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="stats" class="stats">
        <center><h2>Statistic.</h2></center>
        

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Degree</th>
                <th>Institution</th>
                <th>Graduate</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_edu");
            if ($conn -> connect_error) {
                die("Connection Failed:". $conn -> connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM edu";
            $result = $conn -> query($sql);

            if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>". $row["number"] ."</td><td>". $row["degree"] ."</td><td>". $row["name"] ."</td><td>". $row["graduate"] ."</td></tr>";
                }  
            }
            else {
                echo "0 result";
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>

        </table>
        

    </div>
```

Comment: How and where is your css file loaded? If I try what you did here, it works fine for me.

Comment: updated in the bottom section

Comment: fyi, `<center>` is deprecated. Use CSS instead

Comment: @Sven this is how i linked it <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">, it's on the same folder as the PHP

Comment: @brombeer okayy i'll revise it

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply css on table, thead,th,td ,tr. You'r applying css on which is parent div.
here's a example

```css
*{
  font-family:sans-serif;
}



table tr td,th:not(.th-head){
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

table,tfoot{
  border:1px solid #a8afcc;
  word-break: break-all;

}

table:nth-of-type(1) caption {
  font-weight: 800;
}


table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing:1rem 0.1rem;
  table-layout:fixed;/*auto viene por defecto*/
  width: 100%;
  empty-cells: hide;
  text-align:center
}

thead{
  color:white;
  background:rgb(25, 27, 151) ;
}
thead th{
  /* border: none; */
}

table tbody tr:not(tfoot):nth-child(odd) {
    background: #e1e6f8;
}
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #c3cdff;
}

tr:not(.tr-head):hover{
  background:rgb(130, 130, 130);
}
td:hover{
  background:rgb(126, 126, 126);

}

td{
text-align: right;
}

th{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <table >
      
       <thead>
           <tr class="tr-head">
               <th class="th-head">Col 1</th>
               <th class="th-head">Col 2</th>
               <th class="th-head">Col 3</th>              
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
             
               <td>300</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>600</td>
            
           </tr>
           <tr>

               <td>1000</td>
               <td>40</td>
               <td>4000</td>
              
           </tr>
         
        </tbody>
       
   </table>
```

Comment: apparently, it didn't work either, so I instead tried to style the table by inline methods and it still works

Comment: why this wouldn't work. are you importing css from .css file or you putting css in head within `<style></style>` tag. because that should work. and you shouldn't use inline css in most cases.

Comment: from .css files
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

Comment: add my code inside `<style></style>`  in same file, if this works then you file import is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="stats" class="stats">
<h2>Statistic.</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Degree</th>
        <th>Institution</th>
        <th>Graduate</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_edu");
    if ($conn -> connect_error) {
        die("Connection Failed:". $conn -> connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM edu";
    $result = $conn -> query($sql);

    if ($result -> num_rows) {
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<tr>
        <td><?= $row["number"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["degree"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["name"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["graduate"] ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
        }  
    }
    else {
        echo "0 result";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>

</table>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourStyleCode.css">
```

I went ahead and made a little tweak on your css

```
    /*STATISTIC*/
.stats{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.stats h2{
  padding: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.stats th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0e76a7;
  color: white;
}
.stats table {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 9px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.stats td, .stats th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `stats` id you scoped your style. Means that if you style something inside the scope it have not affect on other part your website. But you need the right selectors to go inside the scope. `.stats table tr {...}` for example. In precompiled CSS like SASS etc. it quite easy to write the style. But this is only a note.

```css
.scope {
  tr, td { ... }
}
```